# Test a self-signed domain from selenium hub with Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, gitlab-ci

I have a gitlab ci with selenium test, and everything is perfect when I try to test a site vith valid certificate. But when I try to test a site with self-signed cert, error occured.

Main points in gitlab-ci:

```
  services:
    - name: ..../selenium/standalone-chrome
      alias: selenium

    - pytest -vvv --driver Remote --capability browserName chrome --capability acceptInsecureCerts true  test.py
```

And the python script:

```
class Test():
  def setup_method(self, method):
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
    self.vars = {}
    print(self.driver.__dict__) 
  
  def teardown_method(self, method):
    self.driver.quit()
  
  def test_(self):
    
    self.driver.get("https://validcertificate") -- in this case everything is OK
    
    self.driver.get("https://selfsignedcertificate/") -- in this case i have got "ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID", because no certificate in the hub browser store
```

I have tried the

```
cap = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
cap["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True
```

and

```
desired_capabilities=cap
```

in this case the validcert domain still OK, but the selfsigned run into selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout:)

**Question: What did I miss in the python scipt?

Or how can I setup a certificate for a gitlab service?  (I don't want to create docker image)**

**Logs** (acceptInsecureCerts is "True" in the last part, when I use the "cap["acceptInsecureCerts"] = True" in the script)

```
platform linux -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
driver: Remote
sensitiveurl: .*
metadata: {'Python': '3.9.0', 'Platform': 'Linux-4.15.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.28', 'Packages': {'pytest': '6.1.2', 'py': '1.9.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'variables': '1.9.0', 'selenium': '2.0.1', 'metadata': '1.11.0', 'html': '3.0.0', 'base-url': '1.4.2'}, ...... 'Base URL': '', 'Driver': 'Remote', 'Capabilities': {'browserName': 'chrome', 'acceptInsecureCerts': 'true'}, 'Server': 'selenium:4444'}
.
.
.

---------------------------- Captured stdout setup -----------------------------
{'command_executor': <selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection.RemoteConnection object at 0x7fbec774ecd0>, '_is_remote': True, 'session_id': 'c7292a0f03ac6ef856af1a9f625b65dc', 'capabilities': {**'acceptInsecureCerts': False,** 'browserName': 'chrome', 'browserVersion': '87.0.4280.66', 'chrome': {'chromedriverVersion': '87.0.4280.20 (c99e81631faa0b2a448e658c0dbd8311fb04ddbd-refs/branch-heads/4280@{#355})', 'userDataDir': '/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.RcdGFj'}, 'goog:chromeOptions': {'debuggerAddress': 'localhost:34895'}, 'networkConnectionEnabled': False, 'pageLoadStrategy': 'normal', 'platformName': 'linux', 'proxy': {}, 'setWindowRect': True, 'strictFileInteractability': False, 'timeouts': {'implicit': 0, 'pageLoad': 300000, 'script': 30000}, 'unhandledPromptBehavior': 'dismiss and notify', 'webauthn:virtualAuthenticators': True, 'webdriver.remote.sessionid': 'c7292a0f03ac6ef856af1a9f625b65dc'}, 'error_handler': <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fbec774ef40>, 'w3c': True, '_switch_to': <selenium.webdriver.remote.switch_to.SwitchTo object at 0x7fbec774e430>, '_mobile': <selenium.webdriver.remote.mobile.Mobile object at 0x7fbec774e250>, '_file_detector': <selenium.webdriver.remote.file_detector.LocalFileDetector object at 0x7fbec774eee0>}
----------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')
```